# Recreate part of a forms functionality across domains or autofill a single field on another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've set up a Tictail store as a fundraising method for a high school booster club. I'd like to be able to collect cash donations as well, but (long story short) in order for the club to avoid potential tax liability we'd prefer to funnel these through the district's foundation. The foundation has [a web form](http://supportsps.org/donate/) option that we'd love to make use of. (if possible)

We do not have server access to any of the pages being discussed.

Here are the options I've come up with (in order of preference):

**Option 1:**

Recreate (scrape?) the pertinent parts of the form from the foundation website on our Tictail site and give it the same functionality as it has on the foundation site.

I've been experimenting with jQuery, but I'm kind of lost.

**Option 2:**

- load the foundation site into an `iframe` on our Tictail site
- In the field next to "Donate to Support Springfield Public Schools," autofill it with our groups name.
- when you click submit open the result, but not in the iframe

**Option 3:**

- When a link from out Tictail site to the foundation site is clicked the foundation site loads
- In the field next to "Donate to Support Springfield Public Schools," autofill it with our groups name.

I've got a bit of experience with CSS and Javascript, but just enough to be dangerous. I'm REALLY hoping someone here can understand my problem and offer a solution.

---

Update:

I got everything except the submit button working in a test environment on a different page using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" align="center">

<p>Call the FSPS office at 417-523-0144 to donate or simply enter information below.</p>
<p><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var updateTotals = function() {
    var total = 0;
    var description = "";
    if (!(isNaN(parseFloat(jQuery("#donateQty").val())) || parseFloat(jQuery("#donateQty").val()) <= 0)) {
        total += jQuery("#donateQty").val() * 1;
        description += "$" + jQuery("#donateQty").val() + " donation. ";
    }
    var processingFeeAmount = 0.0;
    if (jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").is(":checked")) {
        processingFeeAmount = total * 0.03;
        total += processingFeeAmount;
        jQuery("#processingFeeAmount").text("$" + processingFeeAmount.toFixed(2));
    }
    if (jQuery("#donateProject").val()) {
        description += " Donation designated for: " + jQuery("#donateProject").val() + ".";
    }
    if(jQuery("#donateAnonymously").is(":checked")) {
        description += " This is an anonymous donation.";
    }
    if (jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").is(":checked")) {
        description += " This includes a processing fee donation.";
    }
    jQuery("#totalPrice").text("$"+total.toFixed(2));
    jQuery("#x_amount").val(total.toFixed(2));
    jQuery("#x_description").val(description);
};
jQuery("#donateQty").change(function() {
    if (!isNaN(jQuery(this).val())) {
        jQuery("#donatePrice").text("$"+(jQuery(this).val()* 1).toFixed(2));
        updateTotals();
    }
});
    jQuery("#donateProject").change(function() {
            updateTotals();
    });
jQuery("#donateAnonymously").change(function() {
    updateTotals();
});
jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        jQuery("#trProcessingFeeAmount").show();
    } else {
        jQuery("#trProcessingFeeAmount").hide();
    }
    updateTotals();
});
});
</script></p>
<form method='POST'>
                        <input id='x_amount' name='x_amount' type='hidden' value='0' /> 
                        <input id='x_description' name='x_description' type='hidden' /> 
                        </p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Donation amount:</td>
<td><input id="donateQty" style="width: 50px;" size="5" type="text" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><span id="donatePrice">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="trProcessingFeeAmount" style="display: none;">
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="3">PROCESSING FEE DONATION:</td>
<td><span id="processingFeeAmount">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="3">TOTAL AMOUNT DUE:</td>
<td><span id="totalPrice">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left !important;" colspan="2">Donation should be directed to:</td>
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="2"><input id="donateProject" style="width:     150px;" size="150" type="text" value="CHS Kilties" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div style="float: right; text-align: left;"><span><label for="donateAnonymously"><br />
<input id="donateAnonymously" type="checkbox" /> I wish to remain Anonymous.</label></span><span>            <label for="donateProcessingFee"><br />
<input id="donateProcessingFee" type="checkbox" /> Add 3% to my gift to cover processing fees, so 100% of my gift goes to FSPS.</label></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Checkout" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>
                   </form>

</div><!-- #content -->


<!--div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
</div--><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form- 7/jquery.form.js?ver=2.52'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/scripts.js?ver=2.4.3'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15690751-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

but when I paste it into the Tictail page, none of the calculations or functionality work.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 will be prevented by the Same Origin Policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) -- if your page is on one domain, you can't use javascript to affect content on a page from another domain (e.g. within an iframe). Option 1 could work but wouldn't involve jQuery -- you would just create a form that has the same form fields with the same names (and the same hidden form fields) that submits to the same location as the original form. There are security options they may have implemented that could prevent this, but probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

I'm finding lots of references to jQuery, JSON and YQL for scraping data from websites not in the same domain. Are these methods legitimate workarounds for the Same Origin Policy? If so, would they render Options 2 and 3 feasible?

Comment: I know very little about building a functional web form. It's one of the things I've never needed till now. I've got it visually recreated, but the function is completely missing. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial or reference to connect the dots?

Comment: I've just been using Chrome's built in Developer Console to dig into the foundation site. I can get the field id's from there, but how do I find the code for what's triggered when someone clicks on the submit button?

Comment: Option 1 is the way to go it seems (as long as their server accepts it - actually it should be prevented for security reasons as you're basically doing a [CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRSF)). However, it would not include javascript. Better kindly ask the server admins to accept an autofill parameter on their form site.

Comment: I understand Bergi. I fully intend to verify everything through them before going live and a link directly to their site will be prominently placed on our page for other types of donations. We accept in-kind donations for several of our events. We will want to be sure to point donors to the foundation for those too.

Answer (score 0):

I got everything but the submit button working with this:

```
<div class="html_content" align="center">

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://supportsps.org/xmlrpc.php" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="supportsps.org &raquo; Feed"     href="http://supportsps.org/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="supportsps.org &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://supportsps.org/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css' href='http://supportsps.org/wp-    content/plugins/contact-form-7/styles.css?ver=2.4.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://supportsps.org/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://supportsps.org/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://supportsps.org/donate/' />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var sOffset = jQuery("#sidebar").offset();
var cOffset = jQuery("#content").offset();
var sdiffHeight = jQuery("#sidebar").outerHeight() - jQuery("#sidebar").height();
var cdiffHeight = jQuery("#content").outerHeight() - jQuery("#content").height();
var height = Math.max(cOffset.top + jQuery("#content").outerHeight(), sOffset.top +     jQuery("#sidebar").outerHeight());
jQuery("#sidebar").height(height - sOffset.top - sdiffHeight);
jQuery("#content").height(height - cOffset.top - cdiffHeight);
});
</script>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div id="content" role="main">
<center><p><h2>Call the Foundation for Springfield Public Schools office at</p>
<p>417-523-0144 or simply use the form below.</h2></p></center>
<p><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var updateTotals = function() {
var total = 0;
var description = "";
if (!(isNaN(parseFloat(jQuery("#donateQty").val())) ||     parseFloat(jQuery("#donateQty").val()) <= 0)) {
total += jQuery("#donateQty").val() * 1;
description += "$" + jQuery("#donateQty").val() + " donation. ";
}
var processingFeeAmount = 0.0;
if (jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").is(":checked")) {
processingFeeAmount = total * 0.03;
total += processingFeeAmount;
jQuery("#processingFeeAmount").text("$" + processingFeeAmount.toFixed(2));
}
if (jQuery("#donateProject").val()) {
description += " Donation designated for: " + jQuery("#donateProject").val() + ".";
}
if(jQuery("#donateAnonymously").is(":checked")) {
description += " This is an anonymous donation.";
}
if (jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").is(":checked")) {
description += " This includes a processing fee donation.";
}
jQuery("#totalPrice").text("$"+total.toFixed(2));
jQuery("#x_amount").val(total.toFixed(2));
jQuery("#x_description").val(description);
};
jQuery("#tabQty").change(function() {
if (!isNaN(jQuery(this).val())) {
jQuery("#tabPrice").text("$"+(jQuery(this).val()* 35).toFixed(2));
updateTotals();
}
});
jQuery("#tableQty").change(function() {
if (!isNaN(jQuery(this).val())) {
jQuery("#tablePrice").text("$"+(jQuery(this).val()* 350).toFixed(2));
updateTotals();
}
});
jQuery("#wilQty").change(function() {
if (!isNaN(jQuery(this).val())) {
jQuery("#wilPrice").text("$"+(jQuery(this).val()* 15.95).toFixed(2));
updateTotals();
}
});
jQuery("#donateQty").change(function() {
if (!isNaN(jQuery(this).val())) {
jQuery("#donatePrice").text("$"+(jQuery(this).val()* 1).toFixed(2));
updateTotals();
}
});
jQuery("#donateProject").change(function() {
updateTotals();
});
jQuery("#donateAnonymously").change(function() {
updateTotals();
});
jQuery("#donateProcessingFee").change(function() {
if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
jQuery("#trProcessingFeeAmount").show();
} else {
jQuery("#trProcessingFeeAmount").hide();
}
updateTotals();
});
});
// ]]&gt;</script></p>
<form method='POST'>
<input id='x_amount' name='x_amount' type='hidden' value='0' />
<input id='x_description' name='x_description' type='hidden' />
</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Donation amount:</td>
<td><input id="donateQty" style="width: 50px;" size="5" type="text" /></td>
<td></td>
<td><span id="donatePrice">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="trProcessingFeeAmount" style="display: none;">
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="3">3% PROCESSING FEE:</td>
<td><span id="processingFeeAmount">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="3">TOTAL AMOUNT DUE:</td>
<td><span id="totalPrice">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left !important;" colspan="2">Direct donation to:</td>
<td style="text-align: right !important;" colspan="2"><input id="donateProject"     style="width: 150px;" size="150" type="text" value="CHS Kilties" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div style="float: right; text-align: left;"><span><label for="donateAnonymously"><br />
<input id="donateAnonymously" type="checkbox" /> I wish to remain Anonymous.</label>    </span><span><label for="donateProcessingFee"><br />
<input id="donateProcessingFee" type="checkbox" /> Add 3% to my donation for processing     fees, so 100% goes to the Kilties.</label></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Checkout" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div><!-- #content -->
<!--div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
</div--><!-- #footer -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-    7/jquery.form.js?ver=2.52'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://supportsps.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-    7/scripts.js?ver=2.4.3'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15690751-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but there's about 2-3 inches of space above the form. [You can see the page here.](http://chskilties.tictail.com/donate) Everything seems to be happening in `<div id="sidebar">` because if I delete that line that space disappears, but so does all the functionality. Any ideas?